# How can create a new column in a dataset filled with random preselected values?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I want to fill the dataset "TEAM" with a new column , and at each row I want to input a random value from lets say a vector of integers (1, 1729, 4679, 10257). My end goal is to link two datasets TEAMS and LEAGUES.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can use the `sample` function with replacement to get as many numbers from a vector as you like. If you need more help than that, you'll need to be more specific

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Is there a reason this is tagged with "sql" and "mysql"? Id your data in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `sample`

```
TEAM$new_column <- sample(c(1,1729,4679,10257),nrow(TEAM), replace = T)
```